# WPF RadioButtonList Set both IsEnabled and IsChecked property from a collection

Tags: wpf, xaml, wpf-controls, isenabled

I have re-styled a ListBox to create a RadioButtonList from this [link](http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/wpfradiobuttonlist)

My requirement is something like this : I have to select a single item from the ListBox at a time(ie **Single** Selection Mode). Also I have to disable/enable ListBoxItem based on property that bind to the collection. So I have set

```
IsChecked="{TemplateBinding IsSelected}"
```

and bound the **IsEnabled** property from my collection.

```
IsEnabled="{Binding IsEnabled}"
```

And the result as follows:
[image]

You can see that some of the records are in disabled state, but still they are selectable.If I remove the **IsChecked** property, it works perfectly as expected. But I need both the **IsEnabled** & **IsSelected** functionlaity.
Then I create a multivalue converter for the IsEnabled property and based on the values I have bind the corresponding value to the property. 
Now I can't select a disabled item from list visually. But when I select a disabled item, I loss the selection. Please check the image :
[image].

and in code behind the **IsChecked** property is set to the first record.
I want to restrict this selection. How can I do that? Is there any settings in xaml will help to do my requirements? Please advice...

Thanks in advance....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you're binding the `IsEnabled` property of the `RadioButton` instead of the `ListBoxItem`. This would disable the `RadioButton`, but not the `ListBoxItem`, which is why it can still be selected.

You should be able to bind the `IsEnabled` property of the `ListBoxItem`, and it will work the way you want.

Based on the link you posted going to the style you're using, that would be in the `ItemContainerStyle` section of the `RadioButtonList` style:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}" >
    <!-- Here -->
    <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="{Binding IsEnabled}" />

    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="5" />
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
                <Border BorderThickness="0" Background="Transparent">
                    <RadioButton Focusable="False"
                                 IsHitTestVisible="False"
                         IsChecked="{TemplateBinding IsSelected}">
                        <ContentPresenter />
                    </RadioButton>
                </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```